# Aspx to Razor syntax converter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a considerable amount of ASPX and ASCX files writed in C# for MVC and I would like to convert them to the new Razor syntax.

Any body knows about some utility that makes this job faster?

Comment: Telerik has released a conversion utility here: https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've written a small piece of code that makes the conversion. I think it could be useful to somebody else. I've learned a lot about regex's [balancing goup definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) on the way.

```
    public static class RazorConversor
{
    public static void ConvertAll(string directory)
    {
        string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Concat(
                         Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.ascx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray();

        foreach (var fileName in array)
        {
            string aspxCode = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            string razorCode = ConvertToRazor(aspxCode);
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, razorCode); //rename manually to update .csproj & source control
        }
    }

    static readonly string[] DefaultNamespaces = new string[]
    {
        "System.Web.Helpers", 
        "System.Web.Mvc",
        "System.Web.Mvc.Ajax",
        "System.Web.Mvc.Html",
        "System.Web.Routing",
        "System.Web.WebPages",
    };

    public static string ConvertToRazor(string aspxCode)
    {
        return ConvertToRazor(aspxCode, DefaultNamespaces); 
    }

    public static string ConvertToRazor(string aspxCode, string[] defaultNamespaces)
    {
        //namespaces
        string text2 = Regex.Replace(aspxCode, @"<%@\s+Import Namespace=""(?<ns>.*?)""\s+%>",
            m => defaultNamespaces.Contains(m.Groups["ns"].Value) ? null : "@using " + m.Groups["ns"].Value);

        //headers
        string text3 = Regex.Replace(text2, @"<%@\s(?<dir>.*?)%>", m =>  "@{ " + m.Groups["dir"].Value + "}"); // Preserves headers

        //expressions 
        string text4 = Regex.Replace(text3, @"<%[=:](?<expr>.*?)%>", m =>
        {
            string expr = m.Groups["expr"].Value.Trim();
            string cleanExpr = Regex.Replace(expr, @"(""(\\""|[^""])*"")|(@""([^""]|"""")*"")|(\([^\(\)]*(((?'Open'\()[^\(\)]*)+((?'Close-Open'\))[^\(\)]*)+)*\))", m2 => "");
            return cleanExpr.Contains(' ') ? "@(" + expr + ")" : "@" + expr;
        }, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        //code blocks
        string text5 = Regex.Replace(text4, @"<%(?<code>.*?)%>", m =>
        {
            string code = m.Groups["code"].Value.Trim();

            Dictionary<string, string> stringLiterals = new Dictionary<string,string>();

            code = Regex.Replace(code, @"(""(\\""|[^""])*"")|(@""([^""]|"""")*"")", m2 =>
            {
                string key = "<$" + stringLiterals.Count + "$>";
                stringLiterals.Add(key, m2.Value);
                return key;
            }); 

            string result = Regex.Replace(code, 
                @"((?<blockHeader>(else|(for|switch|foreach|using|while|if)\s*\([^\(\)]*(((?'Open'\()[^\(\)]*)+((?'Close-Open'\))[^\(\)]*)+)*\))\s*)" + 
                @"((?<fullBlock>{[^{}]*(((?'OpenCurly'{)[^{}]*)+((?'CloseCurly-OpenCurly'})[^{}]*)+)*})|(?<openblock>{.*))|" + 
                @"(?<text>((?!({|}|\s)(for|switch|foreach|using|while|if|else)(\s|{|\()).)+))",
                m2 =>
                {
                    if(m2.Value.Trim().Length == 0 || m2.Value.StartsWith("else")|| m2.Value.StartsWith("}"))
                        return m2.Value;

                    if(m2.Groups["text"].Success)
                        return "@{ " + m2.Value.Trim() + "}\r\n"; 

                    return "@" + m2.Value; 
                }, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Singleline);

            result = Regex.Replace(result, @"<\$\d+\$>", 
                m2 => stringLiterals[m2.Value]);

            return result;
        }, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        return text5; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you've heard the famous quip from Fredrik Lundh: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."

Thanks for the utility, can't wait to give it a whirl.

Comment: I think the world is waiting for a tool that highlights the synthax of regular expressions. In the meenwhile, I think doing that without regular expression will need much much code.

Comment: @Olmo: I've had good experience with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It's great because it highlights the part of the regex you're hovering over and offers context sensitive help. You might want to give it a try - they also offer a desktop version (which I haven't used, yet).

Comment: Wow, this is great!. Thanks a lot Oliver. Since is done in flash, does it use .Net Regex or another dialect?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/

It is a codeplex project that I wrote that automates Olma code with some refinements. There is also an exe download that requires .Net 2.0 I think and you can just drop it into your view folder and it converts everything automatically.

Comment: This worked for me better than telerik's conversion utility, which crashed often and doesn't support master pages.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too early for such a tool, considering that Razor is not yet out of beta and just got syntax highlighting in the latest SP.

However, a google finds [this](http://aspx2razor.codeplex.com/) codeplex project:

> This project is still in early stage and thus does not have any binary release. You might download the source code. You need VS2010 to compile it.