# What are the steps for converting the view engine for an MVC project from .ASPX to Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've inherited an MVC3 project that has a large number of ASPX views that I would like to convert to Razor. This question => [Aspx to Razor syntax converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4422881/138938) is similar to mine, and it helped me find a bunch of options for converting the views themselves, but I'm unclear on the steps I need to take in addition to converting the views.

The first known limitation of [Telerik's razor-converter](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter) is "The tool only works with views and does not deal with the project structure and master pages". This [tool](http://dotnetkicks.com/aspnet/Convert_ASPX_to_Razor_for_MVC_3) claims to be able to convert master pages as well, but it doesn't look like anybody beyond the developer has ever used it.

I think these are the steps I need to take:

1. Use a utility to convert the views
2. Convert the master pages manually (how do I do this?)
3. Modify the project structure (what needs to be modified?)
4. Delete the ASPX files
5. Test the application (any specific gotchas I should look out for?)

Are these the right steps? Can you help me with my questions on steps 2 and 3?

Comment: `but it doesn't look like anybody beyond the developer has ever used it` -- I wouldn't let that bother you too much. It is a one-time conversion; if it works, great. If it doesn't, you haven't lost much; you'll just need to manually convert the master pages anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only tried this on one solution and the actual conversion did a fairly good job.  I downloaded the Telerik converter project, compiled it, and then converted my projects using these command lines:

```
aspx2razor C:\Development\MyProject\MyWebProject\*.ascx C:\Development\MyProject\MyWebProject -r
aspx2razor C:\Development\MyProject\MyWebProject\*.aspx C:\Development\MyProject\MyWebProject -r
aspx2razor C:\Development\MyProject\MyWebProject\*.master C:\Development\MyProject\MyWebProject -r
```

I only needed to go back to add an `@include` for a namespace here and there, and to add a few parenthesis to force the Razor view engine to recognize my inline code properly.  This was also a fairly simple solution, so YMMV.  But even if it converted 80-90% of your views successfully, it's that much less manual work which you would have to perform yourself.  From here, you could also create a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file and make a few minor adjustments to take advantage of Razor-specific layout features.  (Check out Scott Gu's post on it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)

The big issue I had was trying to reconcile the file changes with source control.  Since the classic MVC view engine uses `.aspx`, `.ascx`, and `.master` extensions, I had to manually add the `.cshtml` files to my MVC web project and source control then remove the old versions.  It wasn't difficult, just time-consuming.

In addition, you may need to add all of the necessary `web.config` entries to support the Razor view engine as well if your project was created using MVC 1 or 2.  Projects created with MVC 3 should already have these entries in place, even if it was not originally created as a Razor site.

Comment: >> I had to manually add the .cshtml files  -- Can't you rename the .as*,.master files to .cshtml?