# Convert MVC 2 ASPX into MVC 4 Razor view engine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-2012

I am currently working on MVC 2 with visual studio 2010 and view engine as **ASPX** kind of project.

So I have decided to move with Visual studio 2012 with MVC 4 and view engine as **Razor**.

So could I achieve above task.If so How ?

I would like to hear your experience for similar kind of situation.

Note : My project is a large one.

Comment: We converted stackoverflow from MVC/aspx to MVC/cshtml - it wasn't very much different to "add a few references, write a new default layout (to replace the master page), add .cshtml files in place of .aspx". In most places IIRC I just renamed the .aspx to .cshtml and then fixed up any problems (I ran a global search on `<%` or `%>` in .cshtml files. It *just worked*. I think we copied the razor-esque parts of the config file by simply creating a new razor project and looking at what was different.

Comment: @MarcGravell Could you explain bit more about "write a new default layout (to replace the master page)" ?

Comment: typically you would have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` which assigns the `Layout` to a cshtml version of your old master-page; for example, our `_ViewStart.cshtml` includes `Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";`, where that `~/Views/Master.cshtml` is the converted standard page template

Comment: @MarcGravell My project is very large one.It's having huge number of views.So replacing code syntax will take big time.So Are You suggesting any automated Tool for replace ASPX syntax to Razor ?

Comment: believe it or not, the stackoverflow.com codebase is *also* pretty large with lots of views. I do not recommend any particular automated tools - the conversion was not painful enough to warrant it, for us at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2012 and add source files from your old solution to your new solution one at a time. Moving from MVC3 to MVC4 is easier with a new solution, I have to imagine that going from 2 -> 4 would be even more complex to try to upgrade in-place.

Conversion from ASPX to Razor should probably be done manually. Although there are converters out there (like [this one](http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/) or code like the accepted answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422881/aspx-to-razor-syntax-converter)), I personally wouldn't trust my application to pure automation.

Also, I would probably convert one at a time. In other words, convert from ASPX -> Razor or MVC2 -> MVC4 first and make sure everything works with your conversion. Then convert the other one so that if you run into any problems, you don't have to try to figure out whether it's the version upgrade or the syntax upgrade that caused your problem.

Comment: Could you explain bit more about "Conversion from ASPX to Razor will have to be done manually." ?

Comment: I mean you'll have to convert each file from .an aspx extension to a .cshtml extension and then manually change the markup in the file from ASPX syntax to Razor syntax.

Comment: @Sampath currently you have a whole pile of aspx files; aspx and cshtml have different syntax (for the bits that aren't just html markup). So: somebody (aka "you") needs to go through and *change the code* in each view

Comment: I'm not sure I advocate the "create a new MVC4 project" approach, though... we used a new MVC4 project just to copy the web.config / references / etc - but we had no problems updating our existing project

Comment: I'm basing my answer off of Microsoft's recommended "simplest" approach from MVC3 -> MVC4 (http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806). Quote from that page: "The simplest way to upgrade is to create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project and copy all the views, controllers, code, and content files from the existing MVC 3 project to the new project and then to update the assembly references in the new project to match any non-MVC template included assembiles you are using. "

Comment: If it works well doing an upgrade of the project to MVC 4 without a new project though, that'd be the easier approach.