# ASP.NET MVC migrating from aspx view engine to razor view engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I recently took over an `ASP.NET MVC` application that was started many years ago using the `aspx` view engine.

One of the things I would like to do in an effort to improve the application is to migrate all of the views over to use the `Razor` view engine.  I am looking for some advice on the best way to do this.  I have seen a couple articles discussing using 2 view engines in one application but would like to throw this question out to the group.

**Questions**

Any advice on the best way to incrementally migrate views from aspx to `Razor` without having to re-write them all first?

Is it practical to try to run 2 view engines at once?

Any particular gothchas I might need to be aware of?

Please note that this application needs to be available for sales demos so I can't just take it down while views are  migrated.

Comment: Current version is MVC4

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375029/convert-mvc-2-aspx-into-mvc-4-razor-view-engine

Answer (score 2):

you can use this [tool](https://razorconverter.codeplex.com/) to convert your aspx pages to razor, you just need to copy exe file to your views directory and run it ... that's it ...